# Datastage: String to Timestamp to milli seconds conversion

Tags: string, timestamp, milliseconds, datastage

I'm trying to insert timestamp with milli seconds into a database. I tried following steps but haven't had any luck.

- Extend field value to milli seconds , with length 26 and scale 3.
- Used StringToTimestamp(timestampInString,"%yyyy-%mm-%dd %hh:%nn:%ss.3"), Resulting null value in output.
- Modified the default time Stamp in job properties to %yyyy-%mm-%dd %hh:%nn:%ss.3

Design :

Sequential file --> TX --> destination (SQL/Seq file)

Could you please assist a solution for this?

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: StringToTimestamp(timestampInString,"%yyyy-%mm-%dd %hh:%nn:%ss.3") for type overcast..

Answer (score 1):

try below command in transformer stage and set the target data type as per the requirement, it will give the required result:

```
StringToTimestamp(Columnname,"%yyyy-%mm-%dd %hh:%nn:%ss.3")
```

Answer (score 0):

What you tried looks good so far with one exception:

```
length 26 and scale 3
```

Using Db2 for example you would need to specify length 26 precision 6.
26 and 3 do not fit as

`%yyyy-%mm-%dd %hh:%nn:%ss` has length of 20

Specifying microsenonds is extended attriute is also necessary.

Have a try and provide more details of the target system if you still have problems

Comment: I tried target as SQL and a sequential file but the result having .000 instead of a value.

Comment: have you specified microseconds in the table definition between data type and length? This is really important and needs to be done on the whole way from source to target.

Answer (score 0):

Most important thing is to override the default NLS settings in the job with expected format (%yyyy-%mm-%dd %hh:%nn:%ss.3) which you have already completed.

Now, for the microseconds part which is not being displayed, you can enable the Microseconds extended attribute for the field in the target stage used.

Also you can refer this [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21612931) from IBM which explains a similar scenario